# How to switch functions in a while loop python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that adds, delete and can view dishes a user enters. It seems very simple however, I run into issues with my while loop. When I type in add I am able to add items to my list, however, when I type view the addDish function keeps on looping. I thought I fixed it with my if statement but there's something missing ... !

```
dish_list = []

user_input = ''

def addDish(dish_list):

    user_input = input("Please type the dish you want: ")

    dish_list.append(user_input)

#def deleteDish(dish_list):

def viewDish(dish_list):

    for i in range(len(dish_list)):

        print(dish_list[i])

user_input = input("Please enter a command: ")

while True:

    if user_input == '':

        user_input = input("Please enter a command: ")

    elif user_input == 'add':

        addDish(dish_list, user_input)

    elif user_input == 'view':

        viewDish(dish_list)
```

Comment: As soon as you loop once, `user_input` no longer equals `''`, so your first condition will never trigger again, and will instead trigger on whatever you set `user_input` to in the first iteration

Comment: You also need to call correctly `addDish` correctly, removing the `user_input` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having a while loop, you should call a function that asks for user input once previous input has been handled.

```
dish_list = []

def addDish(dish_list):

    user_input = input("Please type the dish you want: ")

    dish_list.append(user_input)

#def deleteDish(dish_list):

def viewDish(dish_list):

    for i in range(len(dish_list)):

        print(dish_list[i])

def get_input(): 

    user_input = input("Please enter a command: ")

    if user_input == 'add':

        addDish(dish_list, user_input)

    elif user_input == 'view':

        viewDish(dish_list)

    getInput()

getInput()
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit cleaner:

```
dish_list = []


def add_dish(dish_list):
    user_input = input("Please type the dish you want: ")
    dish_list.append(user_input)


def view_dish(dish_list):
    # for dish in dish_list:
    #     print(dish)
    print('\n'.join(dish_list))


while True:
    user_input = input("Please enter a command: ")

    if user_input == 'add':
        add_dish(dish_list)
    elif user_input == 'view':
        view_dish(dish_list)
    else:
        print("Unknown command %s" % user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable user_input never gets set back to empty, so you can never enter a new command since it just takes the last entry you input to user_input, which would be the dish type read in the addDish function. Also, your call to addDish has an extra parameter. I also recommend throwing everything in a main method.

```
def addDish(dish_list):

    user_input = input("Please type the dish you want: ")

    dish_list.append(user_input)


def viewDish(dish_list):

    for i in range(len(dish_list)):

    print(dish_list[i])


def main():

dish_list = []

while True:

    user_input = ''

    if user_input == '':

         user_input = input("Please enter a command: ")

    elif user_input == 'add':

         addDish(dish_list)

    elif user_input == 'view':

         viewDish(dish_list)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed version of the above code snippet:

```
def addDish(dish_list):
    user_input = raw_input("Please type the dish you want: ")
    dish_list.append(user_input)

#def deleteDish(dish_list):

def viewDish(dish_list):
    for dish in dish_list:
        print(dish)

dish_list = []

while True:
    user_input = raw_input("Please enter a command: ")
    if user_input == 'add':
        addDish(dish_list)
    elif user_input == 'view':
        viewDish(dish_list)
    elif user_input == 'exit':
        print('Over!')
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong entry. Retry...')
```

**Execution output:**

```
$python so.py
Please enter a command: add
Please type the dish you want: Bread
Please enter a command: add
Please type the dish you want: Burger
Please enter a command: view
Bread
Burger
Please enter a command: foo
Wrong entry. Retry...
Please enter a command: exit
Over!
$
```